# configuring Azure Search stopwords

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using [Azure Search service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/search/):

How can you configure stopwords?

It insists on indexing the word `is`. I'd like it to work like Amazon CloudSearch where it just ignores words like:

> a, an, and, are, as, at, be, but, by, for, in, is, it, of, on, or, the, to, was.

Comment: From what I know about Azure Search Service, today you can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is now supported.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn879793.aspx for details.

Answer (score 2):

I work on Azure Search. Gaurav is correct - it is not possible today. However, we're working on adding linguistic features to Azure Search, including the stopwords. Stay tuned!